# Symbolic integration of Student's t density in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to integrate the student's t-density in MATLAB but MATLAB seems to fail and just returns the same expression without calculations. Any ideas on how to proceed. I know it should evaluate to 1 but what is the trick to force MATLAB to do it.

```
syms x s mu nu  

g = @(x) gamma(1/2*(nu+1))/(gamma(nu/2)*sqrt(pi*nu*s^2))*(1 + 1/nu*(x-mu)^2/s^2)^(-1/2*(nu+1));

int(g(x), x, -inf, inf)
```

Comment: can you explain me please what do you use `int` for?

Comment: symbolic integration

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it in this way:

```
syms x nu mu s
f = gamma(1/2*(nu+1))/(gamma(nu/2)*sqrt(pi*nu*s^2))*(1 + 1/nu*(x-mu)^2/s^2)^(-1/2*(nu+1))
int(f)
```

And it works! I got some answer:

```
-(gamma(nu/2 + 1/2)*(mu - x)*hypergeom([1/2, nu/2 + 1/2], 3/2, -(mu - x)^2/(nu*s^2)))/(pi^(1/2)*gamma(nu/2)*(nu*s^2)^(1/2))
```

But if i try definite integration it doesn't works:

```
int(f, 0, 1)
ans =
int(gamma(nu/2 + 1/2)/(pi^(1/2)*gamma(nu/2)*((mu - x)^2/(nu*s^2) + 1)^(nu/2 + 1/2)*(nu*s^2)^(1/2)), x, 0, 1)
```

So i went to the help and read this:
If MATLAB is unable to find an answer to the integral of a function f, it just returns `int(f)`. (http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/integration.html)
so the answer is that it can't be solved!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your expression is to complicated for analytical integration. However, your expression seems to be correct and gives exactly 1 if you're using numerical integration:

```
nu = 60.2; % random number
mu = 1.3; % random number
s = 1e6; % random number

g = @(x) gamma(1/2*(nu+1))/(gamma(nu/2)*sqrt(pi*nu*s^2))*(1 + 1/nu.*(x-mu).^2/s^2).^(-1/2*(nu+1));
integral(g, -inf, inf)
```

gives

```
ans = 1.000
```

Of course, this is just a small workaround for certain nu, mu and s.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Matlab, but I can do this in Maple, and I know that Matlab's symbolic computation is very similar to Maple. You need to assume s > 0, then make a substitution z = (x-mu)/s, then assume nu > 0. In Maple code:

```
f:= GAMMA(1/2*(nu+1))/(GAMMA(nu/2)*sqrt(Pi*nu*s^2))*(1 + 1/nu*(x-mu)^2/s^2)^(-1/2*(nu+1)):
J:= Int(f, x= -infinity..infinity):
J1:= IntegrationTools:-Change(J, z= (x-mu)/s, [z]) assuming s > 0:
value(J1) assuming nu > 0;
```

If you do this, then the answer 1 is returned nearly instantly. Note that GAMMA is uppercase and Pi is capitalized in Maple.